# SonarQube Maven plug-in ignores quality profile from server

Tags: maven, sonarqube

The SonarQube Maven plug-in uses the wrong quality profile. It ueses "Sonar way" where it should use "mycompany". Everything works as expected with when I run sonar-scanner on the same project.

How can I force the Maven plug-in to use the correct quality profile?

Comment: did you well associate your project with the mycompany quality profile ? for the right langage ?

Comment: Yes, the project is associated with my custom profile on the server (I think that is the reason why sonar-scanner uses the correct profile).

Comment: how do you run a sonarqube analyse ? do a full, not a preview

Comment: I'm running the analysis via `mvn sonar:sonar` (if that's it what you're asking).

Comment: ok when analyse is over you see them on sonarqube dashboard ? with the right analyse date and time ? a quality profile is written on the side, what is it ? you can change it at this moment and re run an anlyse, it should take the right one

Comment: The analysis I ran via `mvn sonar:sonar` didn't show up in the dashboard. The quality profile shown on the right side is the  "mycompany" profile.

Comment: mycompany profile ? so why did you say it uses the sonar way ?

Comment: The Maven output shows `[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way`.

Comment: what is the date and time of the last analyse on sonarqube dashboard ?

Comment: It is from two ago, when I last tried it with sonar-scanner.

Comment: and you have on the right: Quality Profiles    (Java)mycompany ?

Comment: @BernardDubreuil That is correct.